# Why does my boarding pass read "APIS OK"

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, france, turkey, terminology

I flew from Turkey to France on a direct flight. When I checked in, I saw the boarding pass given to me read "APIS OK".

I thought APIS was [a program of US immigration](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advance_Passenger_Information_System), mostly for passengers to the US. While it is apparently used by other countries, neither France nor Turkey seem on the list.

Why is there such mention on my boarding pass? Does it mean several immigration authorities know about my trip?

Comment: Were you travelling with bees?

Comment: APIS stands for Advanced Passenger Information System. I can see that a stamp, printout, or handwritten note that confirmed the airline had checked your passenger information in advance could easily use that acronym even if they weren't part of that system at this airport.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turkey is [listed by Air France](http://www.airfrance.com/MU/en/local/resainfovol/achat/apis_re.htm) as one of the countries requiring this type of information. The Air France list is slightly different from the Wikipedia list (itself based on an info page from Air Canada) but the latter does not claim to be comprehensive (“these countries include […]”).

I guess this is called “APIS” by analogy with the US system and other countries possibly use the same format but, given the countries involved, I doubt the information is generally shared among them.

Answer (score 2):

According to [a list provided by Air France](http://www.airfrance.com/MU/en/local/resainfovol/achat/apis_re.htm), Turkey is one of the countries that utilizes APIS. Wikipedia's list is probably just out-of-date.

Answer (score 1):

Advance Passenger Information System or APIS gets inserted into your booking either by yourself or if you booked through a travel agent. It is usually inserted for all international travel. The information used is basically your passport number, place of issue, nationality, gender, name and surname all of which can be found on your passport. I think the information goes directly to the airline, and if it is not inserted before you travel it will be inserted at the check in desk when they check your passport, for security purposes. 
I think APIS OK would just suggest that your details have been confirmed and are correct.